# Data migration tool for mysql in new upgraded application with deferrent schema and table structure

Tags: mysql, database, upgrade, etl, database-migration

We are migrating our existing code base to a new robust code base for better performance and reliability. We have a MySQL database with current data. Now we have modified our entities in our spring boot application which will change our schema for the new database structure. I am in search of a tool which will help me migrate all the data from the old MySQL database to a newly created MySQL database with changes according to the latest schema design. I think I will have to write some code to match the new database architecture as no tool will do that refactoring according to my requirement. What tool should be helpful to achieve this?

**Footnotes:**

- I am working in a microservice architecture.
- I have integrated liquibase with maven plugin support.
- I have seen Apache Spark and ETL, but they need

Provide your feedback if you have any relative experience.

Answer (score 0):

We have done the migration of near about 3000 users data from 160(SQL) to near about 75 tables (MySQL) as per new schema.
As per our experience, I can suggest following things - 
1. Prepare mapping sheet of the column in the table to table manner.
2. Migrate them into temporary tables.
3. Test the temporary table's data with the old one. Compare data of each table column by column. You can use ETL tool or excel for comparison.
4. Then write down sp or script for actual migration if no bugs found.